# How can I add pyinstaller to my python path?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After read some posts related a have found an answer that can help me, but i'm trying to do, without sucess.

```
joao@ubuntu-o2:~/Área de Trabalho/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller$ python makespec.py -D janela1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makespec.py", line 24, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import HOMEPATH
ImportError: No module named PyInstaller
```

Some user on stackoverflow said, You have to Add pyInstaller to your Python Path, and I'm looking for a way to add this pyinstaller to my python path but the problem continues.

I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work - I'll expand my answer with more info.

What happens if you move up a directory and run the command:

from:

```
~/Área de Trabalho/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller
```

to:

```
~/Área de Trabalho/pyinstaller-2.0/$ python makespec.py -D janela1.py
```

Comment: python: can't open file 'makespec.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory, The makespec.py file is in:

    ~Área de Trabalho/pyinstaller-2.0/Pyinstaller

And if I try to execute the makespec.py file in this directory the import error occurs. 

I tried to copy and paste the makespec.py but doesn't work.